# Glob / minimatch: how to gulp.src() everything, then exclude folder but keep one file in it

Tags: node.js, gulp, glob, minimatch

I have a project like this:

```
root
  |-incl1
  |-incl2
  |- ...
  |-excl1
  |-excl2
     |- .gitignore  <-- keep this one
     |- (other files)  <-- exclude them
```

I need to write `gulp.src()` that will include all folders except `excl1` and `excl2` **but** keep the `.gitignore` file.

This is my code that doesn't work:

```
gulp.src([
  baseDir + '/**',
  '!' + baseDir + '/{excl1, excl1/**}'
  '!' + baseDir + '/excl2/{**, !.gitignore}'  // <-- doesn't work
], {dot: true})
```

Comment: Whoever invented the globstar-style syntax deserves Hell. Seriously.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
gulp.src([
    baseDir + '/**',                              // Include all
    '!' + baseDir + '/excl1{,/**}',               // Exclude excl1 dir
    '!' + baseDir + '/excl2/**/!(.gitignore)',    // Exclude excl2 dir, except .gitignore
], { dot: true });
```

Excluding single file from glob match was tricky because there's no similar examples in minimatch docs.

https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch

"If the pattern starts with a `!` character, then it is negated".

Comment: Not perfect. Now all `.gitignore`'s under excl2 are kept.

Comment: That wouldn't be a big problem for me. Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Works. The curly braces are not even needed.