# Exclude specific folder after taking specific file from inside the excluded folder - Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Here is what I have so far:

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
// Concat all JS files into a single one called app.min.js
gulp.src([
        'public_html/js/app/' + argv.project + '.js',  // Take project specific file
        '!public_html/js/app/*.js',                 // Do not take all files from app folder
        'public_html/js/**/*.js',                   // Take all JS files that hasn't been excluded
    ])
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/' + argv.project + '/'));
});
```

### The goal is to:

- Take one specific file from **app folder**
- Make sure to exclude all the others, no matter how many files are in the app folder.
- Take all JS files inside **js** folder, but without taking the already excluded folder **app**

### The Problem

is that  when I define `'!public_html/js/app/*.js'`, the specific file specified BEFORE doesn't get added to the result at all. If I remove the exclusion of **app folder**, every file within the app folder gets added to the result, making configuration changes override each other.

The *firewall reasoning* of loading the specific file before excluding the whole folder did not work. 
Is this at all possible?

Thanks in advance.

---

### Solution

```
gulp.src([
    // Do not take all files from app folder except the project file
    '!public_html/js/app/{(*.js),!(' + argv.project + '.js)}',

    // Take all JS files that hasn't been excluded
    'public_html/js/**/*.js',                   
    ])
```

Comment: have you seen this SO question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485612/glob-minimatch-how-to-gulp-src-everything-then-exclude-folder-but-keep-one

Comment: Thank you very much @RajKamal. This question can be closed as duplicated.